# Reloadable Breakpoints in Scripts

Tags: python

Is there a way to have breakpoints within a Python script? I'm looking for something like the following:

```
number = 44838*783274
save("hi.py_breakpoint")
print "Hello!", number
```

Then I can continue where I left off as follows:

```
load("hi.py_breakpoint")
```

Comment: Look at `pdb`/`ipdb`

Comment: I use pdb a lot, but is there a specific way I can exhaust the debugging session into a file?